# Not able to upload files having same name in multiple file upload system

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a code reference [from this site](https://www.sourcecodester.com/tutorials/php/10443/multiple-file-uploads-progress-bar-using-javascript-php.html), that allows me to upload multiple files and also displays loader against each upload. The view comes something like this

[image]

The flow of the entire process is that user clicks on "choose file" and can select multiple files in 1 selection and then on click of "upload button" the files get uploaded.
Another flow that is working here is, on click of "choose file" the user can select 1st file and then again on click of "choose file" he can select 2nd file  and so on.. then at the end he can click on upload button and upload all the files together

The issue comes if i try to upload 2 files with the same name.

While saving in the server folder i have changed the name of the file. But before the upload, if there are 2 files of the same name then it does not upload or else re-uploads the entire set of the files

The code is has multiple files and giving a part of that code here won't give any clarity, so I am giving only a part of the code that i had added to change the name of file at the backend but would really appreciate if you could download the code from [here](https://www.sourcecodester.com/tutorials/php/10443/multiple-file-uploads-progress-bar-using-javascript-php.html) and help me with this issue

Code added to change the name of the file being uploaded at backend(upload.php file in the downloaded folder)

```
function random_number($maxlength = 17) 
    { 
        $chary = array("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o","p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z","0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9","A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"); 
        $return_str = ""; 
        for ( $x=0; $x<=$maxlength; $x++ ) 
            { 
                $return_str .= $chary[rand(0, count($chary)-1)]; 
            } 
        return $return_str; 
    } 

    $random=random_number(); 
    $file_name = strip_tags($_FILES['upload_file']['name']); //File Name 
    $vpb_file_name = $random.$file_name;
```

Can anyone please tell me how to change the name of the files before the upload to the backend

Script responsible for upload [is here](https://jsfiddle.net/yonLj2fy/)

Comment: you can add current Datetime with File name while saving the file.

Comment: @kalai I tried doing so, but then the upload functionality stopped working

Comment: am not a php developer,c# itself we can do same things,then only i can suggest that idea

Comment: can you please edit your answer after trying out suggestion given by @kalai Just need to see how you are storing name containing current timestamp

Comment: am do it in c# side @Developer107

Comment: I am not aware of c#

Comment: this looks not the problem with ajax or js you are using ,the problem is where you are moving it to server from temp directory, because if the file names are same which are submitted via ajax, In the server side foreach loop when we move the file using server side code it moves all the instance of the file having same name at first time when it gets the name and then after when foreach loop comes back again for the 2nd file having same name, then the file will be missing and it resturns error while uploading that file ,

Comment: the source from where the server side code gets the file must have all unique file names. other wise it will grab all the files with same name in the first found loop. renaming it to Datetime and so on is the later part while saving it to destination , but in your case the problem is source not the destination

Comment: as a solution the suggesion here is put the validation that user cant select the files having same name , because java script cannot change the file name on fly because of security reasons.

Answer (score 1):

```
 <input class="uploadGAConnection" #uploadFile  type="file" (change)="uploadGAConnectionDetails($event)" placeholder="Upload file" accept=".csv,.json" (click)="uploadFile.value=null">
```

Simply give a reference and set its value to null on every  click.

Answer (score 1):

As we are also facing the same problem but the we understood that the problem is from server side while saving it to destination, but you can temperory rename the file which is going to be uploaded like

```
var file = $('#select-image-file').get(0).files[0];
var newFileName = 'Some_unique_number'+file.filename;
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', file, newFileName);
```

then submit the formdata so that there will be always unique name for each file before upload and server will save the file with no issues.

Answer (score 0):

make new file name as below

$shortname =time().'-'.$_FILES['newsImage']['name'];

$shortname=str_replace(" ","_",basename(trim($shortname)));

$vpb_file_name=$shortname;